# MKMapView with SwiftUI not showing selectableMapFeatures

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapkit

I'm trying to allow users to select a map pin on the map so that I can use the map information to update the current location.

I introduced `mapView.selectableMapFeatures = [.pointsOfInterest]` and keep track of the selection from the root view. When the user selects any map pin, the `@State` value will be updated.

However, I encountered an issue that the tap selection is not working after introducing `@State` in the root view. Is it because the framework determines the dependency of `MapView` and makes updates that cause the selected map pins not to render?

I also tried to implement a `StateObject` and pass it into `MapView` as `EnvironmentObject` but still failed.

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selected: MKAnnotation?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView(
                coordinate: .init(latitude: 37.3346, longitude: -122.0090),
                setSelected: { selected = $0 }
            )
            if let title = selected?.title {
                Text(title ?? "No Name")     // <--- If I remove the reference to state variable, the map works.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The MapView implementation:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String? = nil
    var setSelected: ((MKAnnotation?) -> Void)?

    var mapView: MKMapView = .init(frame: .zero)

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        mapView.selectableMapFeatures = [.pointsOfInterest]
        mapView.setRegion(.init(center: coordinate, span: .init(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)), animated: true)
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        view.removeAnnotations(view.annotations)
        view.addAnnotation(Annotation(title: title, coordinate: coordinate))
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        MapViewCoordinator(self)
    }

    class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView

        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            return nil
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect annotation: MKAnnotation) {
            if let annotation = annotation as? MKMapFeatureAnnotation {
                parent.setSelected?(annotation)
            }
        }
    }

    class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
        let title: String?
        let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

        init(title: String?, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
            self.title = title
            self.coordinate = coordinate
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered myself.

I found the root cause is `view.removeAnnotations()` because the feature poi is also removed. I have to add some logic to decide whether annotations should be removed, so I added a `StateObject` and pass it into MapView as `EnvironmentObject`:

```
class MapViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedPoi: (String?, CLLocationCoordinate2D)?
    @Published var viewOutdated = false
}
```

to call `removeAnnotations()` appropriately when `viewOutdated == true` in `updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context)`.

Also, the handler of annotation selection should also be modified:

```
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect annotation: MKAnnotation) {
            if let annotation = annotation as? MKMapFeatureAnnotation {
                parent.viewModel.selectedPoi = (annotation.title, annotation.coordinate)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.parent.viewModel.viewOutdated = false
                }
            }
        }
```

But I found the solution looks a bit bizarre and complicated. Still open to other solutions.